# cronjob not working as intended

Tags: linux, shell, sh

this is the script arc_rem.sh(755 permission) which is added in the crontab as follows

```
  00 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * *         * . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and the script arc_rem.sh is as follows

```
  rm /BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/old_arcs.log
  cd /BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch
  LGA=`sqlplus -s tcs384160/tcs#1234 <<\EOF
  set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
  select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log;
  exit;
  EOF`
  echo $LGA;
  U_LIMIT=`expr $LGA - 35`;
  L_LIMIT=`expr $U_LIMIT - 1000`;
  echo $L_LIMIT;
  echo $U_LIMIT;
  LOOP_VAR=$L_LIMIT;
  while [ $LOOP_VAR -le $U_LIMIT ];
  do
   ls  /BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/*_${LOOP_VAR}_*.arc   >> /BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/old_arcs.log;
  LOOP_VAR=`expr $LOOP_VAR + 1`;
  done;
  rm `cat /BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/old_arcs.log`
```

i have included absolute path wherever i could.

this requirement of this script is to delete files older than a sequence(U_limit in the above script) ,it does so by populating the old_arcs.log and doing the rm on that file(last line of code)

following the issues noticed

1)whenever cronjob executes it at interval of 3hrs daily the size of old_arcs is 0 ,hence no files are removed by rm ,but the script works fine when i execute manually sh arcs_rem.sh it populates old_arcs.log as intended and deletes files.

2)
when i do the ps -ef|grep sh during the cronjob execution time the o/p is as follows
it looks like many instances of the same shell script is running,dont know the reason why
and consumes more cpu

```
  oracle   473   455   1 21:00:00 ?         335:37 sh -  c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
  oracle   614   485   1 15:00:01 ?          30:01 sh -c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
  oracle  8278  8240   1 03:00:01 ?         150:37 sh -c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
  oracle 18331 18171   1 18:00:01 ?           2:36 sh -c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null
  oracle  1845  4464   0 06:00:01 ?           0:00 sh -c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
  oracle  9887  9822   1 00:00:01 ?         189:59 sh -c . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

it would be very helpful if anyone could tell me what is wrong with the script or the crontab config and also the workaround

EDIT:

i have checked all the loop variables and they are getting updated fine,what could be the reason for the infinite loops

Comment: Indicate full path of the command when adding it into the crontab.

Comment: i think i have done that ,is there any place i have missed the absolute path ?

Comment: Look at the start and execution times... seems like the script is not running several scripts at the same time, but those are previous scripts which didn't end up well, hence waiting for something to happen without finishing the process.  An edge condition might be wrongly defined, or maybe you need to put some `exit 1` in the script in case something gets unexpected results.

Comment: Here: `00 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * . ./.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` In fact, you are sourcing the script instead of executing it.

Comment: Discarding any error messages is an extremely poor idea, especially when requesting help.

Comment: thnx guys,@jim can u tell me where and how i should add the exit 1 in the aboce shell scrip and @fedorqui im sory im new to shell scripting can u tell me how i should exactly modify the above crontab

Comment: I guess you need something like `/bin/sh  /path/to/.cronprofile;/BIAMD/arch01/usageprd/arch/arch_rem.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use relative paths like `./.cronprofile` in cron job commands.
2. From the `ps` output it looks like your cron jobs are running indefinitely, or at least for very long. You should check for an infinite loop. Cron does not care whether a script is already running when starting another one. Just print `$LOOP_VAR` and `$U_LIMIT` inside the loop to verify that they're changing as expected.
3. [Use More Quotes™.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
4. [Don't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
5. Shell script commands do *not* have to be terminated with `;`.
6. You should use `$()` rather than ``` `` ```.
7. Add `set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset` at the top of the script to enable some very basic error handling. They should work in any [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html).

Comment: im a newbie to shell scripting ,could you tell me  how to  modify the script exactly  to avoid the infinite loop and also the script executes fine without any infinite loop when i execute it manually

Comment: set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset will this wokr across all the os like hpux, solaris and  linux?

Comment: im getting the following error when i tried to add the set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset on the top of the script arch_rem.sh: -o: bad option(s)